Did firearm projectiles start being rifled before barrels?
I think this is a better fit here than on engineering SE (which has a firearms tag), because it pertains to firearm development more so than firearm capabilities.
In any case, I always found the development of rifling very curious.
Even with modern technology, rifling a barrel is expensive and time consuming, so I have no idea how this became widespread practice in the 19th century.
Recently, I came across rifled shotgun slugs, which offer some stabilization to projectiles fired from an otherwise unrifled shotgun barrel.
That made me wonder whether this wasn't the first step in projectile stabilization, since rifling a projectile is comparatively easy.
They can be filed incrementally for prototyping, and cast into a mold for mass-production.
Here's a picture of such a slug.

Did rifled firearm projectiles precede rifled barrels?
If not, any ideas why this innovation didn't happen first?

"Some of the earliest recorded European attempts of spiral-grooved musket barrels were of Gaspard Kollner, a gunsmith of Vienna in 1498 and Augustus Kotter of Nuremberg in 1520. Some scholars allege that Kollner's works at the end of the 15th century only used straight grooves, and it was not until he received help from Kotter that a working spiral-grooved firearm was made." (wiki)

To be pedantic about your question, its an easy answer - arrows were stabilised with fins/feathers/fletches hundreds of years before any firearms existed, so THAT was the first step in projectile stabilisation.

@MikeB I've updated the text to make it clear that I'm referring to firearm projectiles.

It is interesting to note that rifling preceded understanding why it worked by hundreds of years also -- I am not sure who first explained the angular momentum idea. I assume by Newton's time there were people equipped to explain it.

@MikeB: arrow stabilization aerodynamically is quite different than how bullets are stabilized.

@releseabe  I quite agree. Though plenty of people disagree, and go to great lengths to fit helical vanes, or angled (but straight) vanes to their arrows. The edit to the question makes my point invalid anyway.

@releseabe: A non-rifled projectile that isn't perfectly symmetric will be deflected asymmetrically.  One of the most important effects of rifling was to ensure that any (e.g.) upward deflection at some point in a bullet's flight caused by asymmetry would be largely balanced out by downward deflection at other points caused by that same asymmetry.  People may not have understood how a bullet's axis of rotation is affected by drag if if its motion isn't parallel to that axis, but the short term cancellation of asymmetric drag used to be the most important aspect of rifling.

The rifled barrel was first, by centuries
For the majority of the rifle's history it was much easier to make an artisanal rifled barrel once, than artisanal rifled bullets for every shot you wanted to fire.
Rifled barrels
Boutique rifles go back to the 15th century, but even mass-produced rifled long guns are very old indeed. Until the 1800s, all of these weapons fired conventional round bullets because these were extremely cheap to produce - for round balls, one only had to drop molten lead from a great height into water.  The soft bullet would deform when fired and squeeze into the barrel's rifled grooves, and thereby spin.
During the early 1800s, development in ballistics identified that elongated bullets could achieve much better accuracy and impact - whether fired from a musket, a rifle, or a cannon. Eventually this led to the development of the Minié "ball" as the dominant bullet shape.
Making the bullets into more complicated shapes that that - even something as simple as hexagon shaped, never mind rifled - was just too hard at the time.

Since manufacturing hexagonal bullets was beyond the South’s capabilities, each Whitworth rifle came with a bullet mold to cast a cylindrical lead projectile that formed itself to the bore when fired.

You needed one mold per rifle because each soldier would want to produce their own bullets in the field:

Soldiers often made their own bullets or recycled old and or used ammunition by melting it down and re molding it in a similar way to how musket balls are made.

Rifled projectiles
Shotgun slugs were only rifled in 1898. The main purpose was to fit the barrel better and dig through the fouling caused by black powder.
Since the bullet is softer than the barrel, the only thing that gives it spin as it fires out of the gun is air resistance. Compared to metal, air is rather soft - so the amount of spin on these slugs was negligible.
In fact these experiments with rifled projectiles in a smoothbore barrel postdate even attempts to use rifled projectiles together with rifled barrels - once again to improve barrel fit rather than make it spin more.

Thank you for the answer. It's really good in detailing that even though “casting a shaped projectile” sounds fairly simple, it might have been prohibitively difficult compared to the alternative. But was it really more difficult than rifling a barrel?

@TheChymera This is not a primary historical source but might give you an idea of why the non rifled bullet was so much easier to manufacture: https://civilwartalk.com/threads/how-were-minie-balls-manufactured.112394/ The more important part of the answer however is that the rifled slug doesn't really spin that much.

During the 'English' Civil War, Prince Rupert is said to have shot two holes in a weathercock in Stafford using a 'screw'd (rifled) horsman's pistol'. Of course, such weapons were rare at the time.

This economic answer is good, but to expand on the ineffectiveness: the era's shaped bullets deform to fill the bore (eg Minié ball), which means rifling on the bullet itself is forward of the obstruction and thus not contributing meaningfully to spin. A shaped bullet that did not deform and was in a smooth barrel would necessarily be a loose fit, reducing velocity and adding off-axis tumbling forces. Useful spin from a rifled bullet in a smoothbore requires brittle materials, very tight machining tolerances, and non-fouling propellant. More expensive and less feasible than rifling barrels.

Spin predates firearms
Long before firearms were a thing, arrows were fletched to make them spin in flight. From the Worshipful Company of Fletchers, the first good written evidence comes from Roger Ascham, "Toxophilus or the Schole of Shooting", in 1545. The Fletchers say

Nowadays in the UK it is practice to use only the left wing, but for how long this has been done is not known.
Contrary to some belief it is not necessary to set fletchings on the slant in order to make the arrow spin. Provided that each feather is from the same wing, right or left, the arrow will spin because the feather has a rough side which produces lift and a smooth side over which air flows freely.

The spin of an arrow can easily be seen in flight, especially if one feather is a different colour. So this is entirely deliberate, not accidental.
How to make arrows which shot best was a highly skilled activity - in earlier ages it would have been a serious military secret, and later on it became a guilded trade to share knowledge amongst masters (and exclude it from everyone not a guild member).
It is possible that people forgot about spin on projectiles and had to reinvent it, but it seems unlikely since archers and cannons definitely coexisted in time. It is far more likely that people either couldn't work out how to put spin on a cannonball or didn't have the technology at the time to make it happen.
